# File is only written at the end of my program

Tags: python, file, while-loop, pygame, yaml

I'm creating a game in Python with pygame and I have to update my file when I update my pygame display.
But when I try to write it, It's only written at the end of my program.

The class where I try to write the file

```
class GameReader():

    def __init__(self):

        self.file_content = [
            {'last_edit': 0},
            {
                'map_infos': {
                    'p1': 0,
                    'p2': 0,
                    'p3': 0,
                    'p4': 0,
                    'p5': 0,
                    'p6': 0,
                    'p7': 0,
                    'p8': 5
                }
            }
        ]

        self.update_file()

    def update_file(self):
        with open('gameFiles/game.yaml', 'w') as file:
            yaml.dump(self.file_content, file)
            file.close()
```

The instance of `GameReader()` is stored in a class `Game()`

```
while running:

    # ajout du menu
    screen.blit(game.menu.image, game.menu.rect)

    # ajout du boutton de départ
    screen.blit(game.start_btn.image, game.start_btn.rect)

    # update
    pygame.display.flip()

    # update de la game file
    game.game_reader.update_file()

    # recuperer les events
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # si fermeture de fenetre
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```

Comment: so you need maybe to do game.update_file()

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Regardkess of what the problem is, I doubt you really want (or need) to update the file every iteration of the display loop. Probably best to just update the in-memory `self.file_content` dictionary and only write the file when the game ends.

Comment: It only ***appears*** that the file is being updated at the end of your program (and it nothing to do with whether the file was flushed or not). The file was updated many times, but the final results will — not surprisingly — be the last rewrite that occurred before the program ended.

Comment: I've found with file.flush()

Comment: Files generally don't need to be flushed because that happens automatically when they're closed. Also, when using `with` to open a file, it will be closed automatically, therefore so you don't need to do either one of them. I'm not sure how you're determining the last time the file was written, but think you must be mistaken about `flush()` fixing the problem about what's going on. Of course without a [mre], we'll never know…

Answer (score 0):

Files are written via a buffer, so you need to flush it.

```
file.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def update_file(self):
        with open('gameFiles/game.yaml', 'w') as file:
            yaml.dump(self.file_content, file)
            file.flush()
            file.close()
```